# Hot Answers page shows community wiki answers

Tags: bug, community-wiki

The hot answers page isn't supposed to show answers that are community wiki. But it does anyway.

Examples:

- jQuery on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/hot?filter=all
- C++ on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/hot?filter=all
- FAQ on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq/hot?filter=all

[image]

It worked fine before, but I don't know when it broke since I rarely view these pages.